# Django - Error downloading image

Tags: python, django, image

I am developing a function to download an image.

but I am getiing this error

```
coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, ImageFieldFile found
```

It's the code:

```
def download_image(request, image_id):
    img = Base.objects.get(base_id=image_id)
    wrapper      = FileWrapper(open(img.file))  # img.file returns full path to the image
    content_type = mimetypes.guess_type(filename)[0]  # Use mimetypes to get file type
    response     = HttpResponse(wrapper,content_type=content_type)  
    response['Content-Length']      = os.path.getsize(img.file)    
    response['Content-Disposition'] = "attachment; filename=%s" %  img.name
    return response
```

Answer (score 0):

`img.file` is a `ImageFieldFile` object, `open()` requires a string. You need to do `open(img.file.name)` to get the actual file path.